# Unexpected R memory management behaviour

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, promise

I spent the past few day hunting what I thought was a memory leak somewhere in an R program I wrote. It turned out it was caused by some R features I don't really grasp. My hunch is that it has to do with promises and lazy evaluation. Here is an example to reproduce the problem:

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(1E7), 1000)
format(object.size(M), "Mb") ## An 80 Mbs matrix
gc() ## Memory usage should be around 80 Mbs
LF <- apply(M, 1, function(X) {sdX <- sd(X); function(X) X / sdX})
format(object.size(LF), "Mb") ## 2.9 Mb (isn't it a lot for a few functions? but it's not really the point)
gc() ## Memory usage is at 158 Mbs event though our workspace only contains two objects of 80 and 2.9 Mbs
rm(M)
gc() ## Back to around 80 Mbs but M is gone
rm(LF)
gc() ## Back to normal
```

You can see that memory usage will grow out of hands if we repeat the operation too often.
It seems that R needs to store the entire matrix to be able to call the functions in `LF`. Any insights on what happens when we create the functions in `LF`? A workaround?

Comment: You are creating closures there. Check out `ls(envir = environment(LF[[1]]))`. R has to associate these objects with each function, otherwise they wouldn't work if you removed `M` from the global environment. My advice: Don't do this. If you described why you are doing this, we could suggest alternatives.

Comment: The goal is to create functions that transforms a set of variable. Each column of the matrix is a different variable in the example. Note that this is a simplified version of what I do in my program. I understand that R has to save `sdX` somewhere but why does it store the entire column? It could just store the value of `sdX` that is small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enclosing environment of the function you return is the local environment of the function passed to `apply`. Obviously, the function parameters must be stored in this environment. Usually this environment is lost after the call, but you preserve it because you return a closure. You can delete undesired objects:

```
LF <- apply(M, 1, function(X) {sdX <- sd(X); rm("X"); function(X) X / sdX})
ls(envir = environment(LF[[1]]))
#[1] "sdX"
```

However, I still don't see a reason for using closures and recommend redesigning your whole approach. E.g., in this specific example I'd return the standard deviations and pass them as a parameter to the transforming function.